# Rank statement is causing query to run very slow

Tags: t-sql, rank

[image]I have the following query. The rank in the ‘causing the query to run a very long time. I am trying to reduce the time. 
Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

```
SELECT
                                 REC.INPATIENT_DATA_ID
                               , RANK() over (Partition by PATS.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID, MEAS.FLO_MEAS_ID order by RECORDED_TIME) 'VITALS_RANK' 
                               , MEAS.RECORDED_TIME
                               , PATS.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID
                               , PATS.PAT_ID
                               , PATS.CONTACT_DATE
                               , MEAS.FLO_MEAS_ID
                               , PATS.DEPARTMENT_ID
                               , PAT.IS_TEST_PAT_YN
                               , PATS.HOSP_DISCH_TIME
                               , PATS.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME
                         FROM CLARITY.DBO.IP_FLWSHT_REC  REC
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY.DBO.PAT_ENC_HSP PATS ON PATS.INPATIENT_DATA_ID = REC.INPATIENT_DATA_ID 
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY.DBO.CLARITY_DEP AS DEP ON PATS.DEPARTMENT_ID = DEP.DEPARTMENT_ID
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY.DBO.PATIENT_3 PAT ON PAT.PAT_ID = PATS.PAT_ID  
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY.DBO.IP_FLWSHT_MEAS MEAS ON REC.FSD_ID = MEAS.FSD_ID
```

Comment: OUt of interest, why do you say `RANK` is the cause here? Are you saying that without the windowed `RANK` expression the query runs fast? Can you supply the query plan (use Paste the Plan).

Comment: yes. trying to figure out how to attach the plan to this comment...

Comment: Lamu, how do I attach the plan here? thanks

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: I added an image of the plan. Does that work for you?

Comment: @SHELL no, not really. We can't interact with an image. Like myself and HABO mentioned, use Paste the Plan. Also, you didn't answer my question in my comment.

Comment: Yes, without rank, my query runs fast. I'm so sorry but I'm still trying to figure out the paste the plan.